# Как работать с размером в unity (юниты, метры, физика)?

Tags: unity3d

Моя задача - создать физически реалистичную 2D игру. Но я не могу понять, как работать с размером в unity. Проще говоря - а какой размер у моих объектов в юнити?

**Пример**

В жизни у меня есть коробка 30 на 30 см. Я хочу добавить её в игру.
В фотошоп, рисовать коробку 30 на 30 см (на "два экрана") не имеет смысла. Это огромный рисунок с ненужной детализацией.

Я рисую коробку, размером 300 на 300 пикселей. Добавляю её как ассет в игру, перетаскиваю на сцену.

**Возникает вопрос - какого размера у меня эта коробка в игре? 3см, 3 метра, 300 метров?**

Почитав доки Unity вижу
у спрайтов есть параметр pixels per unit - по умолчанию он 100. То есть моя коробка 300 пикселей = 3 юнита = 3 метра?
[image: Коробка]

Но на картинке коробка занимает полторы клетки. Клетка же юнит? Почему не занимает 3 клетки?
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Разве ты сам не устанавливаешь масштаб объектов в проекте? Добавь куб 100х100 пикселей, и пусть это будет 1 сантиметр, какая разница

Comment: Вроде нет. Физика. Именно по этому 1 юнит = 1 метру.